# How to create Relationships betweem two nodes for Bulk Records

Tags: neo4j, cypher

`I have Millions of records in Existing Database (Psql) that i have already imported into Neo4j using C# .Now how can we create Realtionships for millions of record.

For Example 1st Drug(node) Table seems like this :

| ISR | Drug Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DrugName1 |
| 1 | DrugName2 |

For Example 2nd Reaction(node) Table seems like this :

| iSR | Reaction Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | HeadPain |
| 2 | Rash |

Ths is my Cypher Query

```
MERGE (d:Drug {id:'1', drug:'DrugName1'}),(r:Reaction{id:'1',reactionname:'ReactionName1'})
```

`

Please help me on this ,Thanks in Advance

Comment: how do you join Drugs to Reaction? thanks

Comment: using ISR  column for both table

Comment: please add ISR column in your example. thanks

Comment: I have added ISR in my example  thanks!..

Comment: Once you have node Drug (d) and Reaction (r) created, you can also create the relationship. Put it next on your query.